# Give Error 'mach_msg_trap' error

Tags: iphone, uitableview

when run the following code it give proper result but when go to another view and go back an further search it give the  'mach_msg_trap' error

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
AppDeleget=  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
ProcessView *Process=[[ProcessView alloc] init];
[Process SearchProperty:AppDeleget.PropertyURL page:AppDeleget.Page];
[Process release];
for(NSDictionary *status in AppDeleget.statuses)
{       

    NSMutableString *pic_string = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[status objectForKey:@"picture"]];  

    if([pic_string isEqualToString:@""])
    {

        [ListPhotos addObject:@"NA"];

    }
    else
    {

        NSString *str= [[[status objectForKey:@"picture"] valueForKey:@"url"] objectAtIndex:0];
        [ListPhotos addObject:str];  
        [str release];

    }
}
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(LoadImage) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

[AppDeleget.MyProgressView stopAnimating];
[AppDeleget.Progress removeFromSuperview];
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[TableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[TableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}


 // NSString *bedsbaths=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Beds:%@ Baths:%@",[[AppDeleget.statuses valueForKey:@"beds"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[[AppDeleget.statuses valueForKey:@"baths"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.mlsno.text=[[AppDeleget.statuses valueForKey:@"mlsno"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.price.text=[[AppDeleget.statuses valueForKey:@"price"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.address.text=[[AppDeleget.statuses valueForKey:@"address"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//  cell.bedsbaths.text=bedsbaths;
cell.bedsbaths.text=[[AppDeleget.statuses valueForKey:@"dispDetails"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;




return cell;
}


-(void)LoadImage
{
for(int x=0;x<[ListPhotos count];x++)
{   
    if ([ListPhotos objectAtIndex:x] == @"NA") 
    {

        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"No_image.png"];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downloadDone:) withObject:img waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
    else
    {   
        NSData *imageData =[ListPhotos objectAtIndex:x]; 
        id path = imageData;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
        NSLog(@"%@",url);
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downloadDone:) withObject:img waitUntilDone:NO];

    }
}

 }
 -(void)downloadDone:(UIImage*)img {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0];

if(img == nil)
{
    TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
    cell.myImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"No_image.png"];
    ++count;
    [TableView reloadData]; 

}
else
{
    TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
    cell.myImageView.image=img;
    ++count;
    [TableView reloadData]; 
}   

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're releasing objects which were not allocated:

```
NSString *str= [[[status objectForKey:@"picture"] valueForKey:@"url"] objectAtIndex:0];
[ListPhotos addObject:str];  
[str release];
```

Here, 'str' shouldn't be released, because it's an autoreleased object.